# create file name based on CSV column data using gawk

Tags: csv, gawk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a very messed up CSV file where the header looks the following:

**`maindata.csv`**

```
time;area;measurement1;measurement2;measurement3;.....measurement12
```

I was able to split the single large file based on measurement names separately using the following `gawk` command format in order to keep each separate file in the following CSV Format:

```
measurement1.csv -> has csv header [time,area,measurement1]
measurement2.csv -> has csv header [time,area,measurement2]
....
measurement12.csv -> has csv header [time,area,measurement12]
```

**`gawk` command**:

```bsh
gawk -F';' '{print $1","$2","$X}' maindata.csv > /splitdata/measurementX.csv
```

where `X` is the column number of the respective measurement.

I had to do this manually everytime on the terminal, and wanted to know if I could actually somehow extract the measurement column name using `gawk` and replace the above command with some variable than can automatically be used to name the file `measurementX.csv`

#### Example

```bsh
gawk -F';' '{print $1","$2","$3}' maindata.csv | head -n 1 > splitdata/measurement<get the column 3 name here>.csv
```

*P.S.* for brevity the column names are `measurementX`. In practice, they can be `temperature`, or `pumpmotor` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`measurements.awk`:

```
BEGIN{FS=";";OFS=","}
{
    for (X=3;X<=NF;X++){
        if (NR==1){name[X]=$X}
        print $1,$2,$X > name[X]".csv"
    }
}
```

See that `NR==1` is only true for the header. So we save the measurements names in the array `name`, and then proceed to print each set `[time,area,measurement]` in the corresponding file.

```
$ gawk -f measurements.awk file
$ cat file
time;area;temperature;pumpmotor;diameter
1;2;3;4;5
6;7;8;9;10
```

```
$ cat diameter.csv 
time,area,diameter
1,2,5
6,7,10
$ cat temperature.csv 
time,area,temperature
1,2,3
6,7,8
$ cat pumpmotor.csv 
time,area,pumpmotor
1,2,4
6,7,9
```